# Get item from an dynamical inserted ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to get an item from a listview. I am creating many dynamic layouts ( depends from the output of the database ) and when iam clicking on the view i wanna display the data in another Activity in Textviews. How can i arrange this?

Here is my Activity with the ListView:

```
 public void getRoute() {

        mdbH = new DatabaseHelperActivity(this);
        cursor = mdbH.fetchallRoutes(intent.getStringExtra("StartHaltestelle"),intent.getStringExtra("ZielHaltestelle"), intent.getStringExtra("Zeit"));
        ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity> route = new ArrayList<DefineRouteActivity>();
        int i = 0;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            i++;
            route.add(new DefineRouteActivity(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(4)));
        }
        if(i == 0){
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    PlanOutputActivity.this).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.pDInfo));

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.pDErrorMessage));

            // Setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlanActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

        ListView lvList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListOutput);
        ArrayAdapter<DefineRouteActivity> adapter = new RouteAdapterActivity(this, route);
        lvList.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent detail = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailOutputActivity.class);


                startActivity(detail);
            }
        });

    }
```

Here is my Activity where the Strings should be dispalyed with the following four TextViews:

public class DetailOutputActivity extends Activity{

```
Intent detail;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detailoutputlayout);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent detail) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, detail);

    detail = getIntent();
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        TextView txStart = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txDetailOutputStart);
        TextView txEnd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txDetailOutputEnd);
        TextView txTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txDetailOutputTime);
        TextView txRoute = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txDetailOutputRoute);

        txStart.setText(detail.getStringExtra("start"));
        /*txEnd.setText(detail.getStringExtra("EndStop"));
        txTime.setText(detail.getStringExtra("Time"));
        txRoute.setText(detail.getStringExtra("Route"));*/
    }
}
```

Here is my layout which get inserted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/outputlayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/ligthgrey">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txOutputDeparture"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Abfahrt "
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:maxLength="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txOutputDuration"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDeparture"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Dauer"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txOutputTransition"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txOutputDuration"
            android:text="Umstieg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and of course my Listview id is ListOutput!

Answer (score 0):

In onItemClick() use index of clicked item and take that it from your data source which with which you have made adapter. (Ex. ArrayList object passing to adapter). And then put that in Intent using Bundle/Extra and getIntent in Detail activity.

To get view of selected list Item and its data(text) do like below:-

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylistviewtextview);
        //here view is your selected list Item view
        String keyword = txt.getText().toString();
        Log.v("value ", "result is " + keyword);

    }
});
```

Comment: but how can i get this Textview ... my inserted layout includes 4 TextView... should i get them by findViewById?

Comment: are you talking about TextViews of your DetailOutputActivity or Textviews of your list item.

Comment: i am talking about the List elements... how can i get those strings from the textvies?